# Mathematica precision on extensive eigenvalues calculations

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, precision-and-accuracy

Im trying to evaluate some dot products with eigenvectors and matrices using Mathematica. My problem is the following:

To an given matrix 6x6:

```
h[kx_, ky_, t1_, B1_, B2_, 
  B3_] := -4 t1 (tx (Cos[kx]) + ty (Cos[ky])) - 
  B1*O1- B2*O2 - 
  B3*O3
```

Where the variables `tx`, `ty`, `O1`, `O2`, `O3`, `T` are given on the code down on this post.

I need to get the 2 lowest eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors at `kx=0`, `ky=0`, to do so, i use

```
NLowestEiv[expr_, n_] := 
 Sort[Transpose[Eigensystem[expr]], Re[#1[[1]]] < Re[#2[[1]]] &][[1 ;; n]]

NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1,B1,0,0],2]
```

For `B1` between -1 and 1

And then compute this w matrix:

```
w=Table[Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1,B1,0,0],2]][[i]].Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1, B1,0,0],2]][[j]],{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]
```

For different values of B1.

The problem is, the result that i need depends on the signal of the elements of `w` and mathematica, due to the computational precision return really small values and oscilates very much between positive and negative values. This oscilation can be seen by using manipulate or plot:

```
Manipulate[Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1,B1,0,0],2]][[1]].Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1, B1,0,0],2]][[2]]], {B1,0,0}

Plot[Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1,B1,0,0],2]][[1]].Conjugate[NLowestEiv[h[0,0,1, B1,0,0],2]][[2]]], {B1,0,0}
```

How can i eliminate this oscilation?? I tried to use If as conditionals but can´t make it work.

Here is the definition of the matrices used on the top

```
O1={{10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -8, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0, -8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10}}

O2={{60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -180, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0, 120, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -180, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60}}

O3={{0, 0, 0, 0, 12 Sqrt[5], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12 Sqrt[5]}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {12 Sqrt[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  12 Sqrt[5], 0, 0, 0, 0}}

tx={{15/56, 0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0}, {0, 3/56, 
  0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56}, {-((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, 
  3/28, 0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0}, {0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, 3/28, 
  0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28)}, {(3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, 
  3/56, 0}, {0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, 15/56}}

ty={{15/56, 0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0}, {0, 3/56, 
  0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56}, {-((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, 
  3/28, 0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0}, {0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, 3/28, 
  0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28)}, {(3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0, -(3/(28 Sqrt[2])), 0, 
  3/56, 0}, {0, (3 Sqrt[5])/56, 0, -((3 Sqrt[5/2])/28), 0, 15/56}}

T={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: I don't think the site allows image links like `https://prnt.sc/tvxkht`.  Use imgur through the image button on the edit window.  In any case, the link doesn't work.

Comment: The link is just the output of plot graphic, it cam be visualized on  mathematica

Comment: You should upload the image to imgur though the edit window as Michael E2 iterated, this will be useful for those who come to this question to answer & find answers in the future. Many users will not click on unfamiliar links. Also, what version are you using? Recently there have been some issues regarding `Eigensystem` which were fixed, and so if you are not updated fully, this may be where your issue originates.